What are some best practices for coding a satellite orbit propagator and ground track plotter?
I've seen interesting projects like this and I've been doing a decent amount of orbit propagation (numerically integrating state vectors, accounting for perturbations, etc.) in python and animating some plots with matplotlib to get a bit better at the astrodynamics. I want to build a full, interactive simulator in three.js (really, Next.js and React three fiber) and wanted to check that my plan is sound, and ask for any recommendations.
I plan to:
(1) take either classical orbital elements (converting them to r,v) or some initial conditions for a state vector (the components of r and v) and numerically integrate the orbit, then animate it around a 3d model of the Earth.
(2) find where the satellite intersects the Earth (its SSP) on its vector to the model's center in the course of its orbit and convert the spherical polar coordinates of that intersection to latitude/longitude.
(3) animate the array of lat/long coords on a Mercator projection.
I've seen some algorithms for doing the ground track computations, but this seemed like something that would work without issue. Any ideas or resource recommendations?

If it helps, you can find some orbital mechanics functions and lat-lon conversion functions written in javascript here. Use at your own risk! (But if you uncover any errors in this code, please let me know!)

Just FYI, the orbit data published by space-track are specifically designed only to work with the SGP software they distribute.  So the results produced by your own propagator won't match their results.

@GregMiller I actually hadn't come across space-track before, but it seems interesting. I'm mostly just working with hypothetical satellites (e.g., by specifying their state vector or elements, and evolving it in time). I'm at the last steps of doing the ECEF to Geodetic conversion right now, but it's pretty complex. I'd be interested in any resources or advice!

The Python package Skyfield (and in Github) has the calculation to obtain "subpoints" on the WGS84 ellipsoid from various other coordinate systems. The difficulty of the calculation for the ground track rises rapidly with the accuracy you require. For a few kilometers, it should be very simple, but at the level of meters there are all kinds of messy topological and time details.

Vasco Asturiano has done a lot of the work you seem to want to do. His react-globe library has a lot of good stuff - perhaps start by looking at his satellites example and demo.

For anyone interested, here's what I have for now: https://satellite-propagator.vercel.app/
I'm still building out most of the features I want it to have (and a lot of it is unfinished, along with there being no input validation, e.g., I haven't covered cases where e > 1 or e = 1 and so on), but it's a start! I'm numerically integrating the orbits on a python backend and displaying everything in a Next.js frontend with three.js.
